# Firing and listening for Android Intents in Javascript in regular Android web browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, android-intent

I cannot find much recent information on this topic. **Does anyone know if there is any way to both fire an Android Intent (any Intent) and listen for an Android Intent being broadcast within a HTML/JavaScript application running inside a regular Android web browser, such as Chrome?**

We currently do this in our HTML/JavaScript web applications using Cordova and an Android Intents Cordova Plugin and it works perfectly. But we would like to move away from Cordova and back to using regular mobile browsers.

We are currently running our web apps on Zebra laser scanner Android devices via Cordova and the Intent fire/listen is to interact with the Zebra laser scanner. This is what we want to replace via standard Chrome web browser instead.

Anyone know if there is any possibility at all to fire/listen for any Android Intents from inside Chrome?

And yes, we are very familiar with the Zebra Enterprise Browser which would handle this situation easily (without Intents), but that is not free and we have a huge amount of Zebra devices, so that option is out at this point due to cost.

Thanks,

Brendan

Comment: "Does anyone know if there is any way to both fire an Android Intent (any Intent) and listen for an Android Intent being broadcast within a HTML/JavaScript application running inside a regular Android web browser, such as Chrome?" -- that would be a fairly substantial security flaw.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem. There is still no other way than wrapping a WebView in a minimal Android app.
Here is an example of an App passing Intents to a WebSocket you can listen to in JS:
https://github.com/darryncampbell/datawedge-websockets-bridge

You can also use a WebMessageChannel in Android if you just want to listen to a MessageChannel in JS:
https://www.demo2s.com/android/android-webmessageport-tutorial-with-examples.html